# What will happen to the rank of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Say $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix having rank say $r$ and we obtain a matrix $B$ by changing one element of $A$, having rank say $s$. Then what can we say about the rank of $B$? Increase, decrease or remain same? How can we compare between $r$ and $s$?

Edit: Among the following which is/are possible?
$$s\leq r+1,~ r-1\leq s$$~or~$$s=r-1?$$

Comment: It might increase, decrease, or remain the same.  It can differ by at most $1$ though.

Comment: Can we infer $s=r-1$?

Comment: Without any additional info all we can say is that $s=r-1$ OR $s=r$ OR $s=r+1$.

Comment: See my edit @Bye_World

Comment: Again, there are exactly three possibilities and I've listed them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}
$$
which has rank $1$.  The new matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$
has rank $2$. On the other hand, the new matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}
$$
also has rank $1$.  On the other hand, the new matrix
$$
B = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}
$$
has rank $0$.  So, there is no guarantee of what the rank will be, except to say that it will be within $1$ of the original.

---

As for your edit: the inequalities will *always* hold.  $s = r-1$ is possible, but might not hold.

Comment: Why $s=r-1$ might not hold?

Comment: See the second and third examples.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the first and second examples.